# Oracle SQL Query Optimization (Left joins, indexes)

Tags: sql, oracle, select, optimization

The following query gets stuck when a table is added in left join set. The query runs smooth if last join is excluded. but gets stuck if last join is included. I have tried ALL_ROWS, FIRST_ROWS optimizer hints as well. There are around 5500 expected rows from cps_taskhis for '20190404'.

Notes:

- Table cpsmgt.cps_orderhis.orderid is indexed column. {screenshot 1}.
- Table cpsmgt.cps_taskhis.orderid is also an indexed column which is being joined to cpsmgt.cps_orderhis.orderid in last left join. {screenshot 2}

**Screen shot 1:**
[image]

**Screen shot 2:**
[image]
**SQL Query**

```
SELECT /*FIRST_ROWS*/
    t.taskid task_no,
    t.orderid order_id,
    DECODE(t.priority,50,'Low',100,'Medium',200,'High','Other') task_priority,
    t.taskname task_name,
    TO_CHAR(t.createtime,'HH24') creation_hour,
    t.createtime create_time,
    t.completedtime completed_time,
    ( to_timestamp(t.completedtime,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') - to_timestamp(t.createtime,'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') ) time_difference,
    op1.user_name initiator_login,
    rd1.name role_assigned_maker,
    op2.user_name checker_login,
    rd2.name role_assigned_checker,
    t.taskstate task_state,
    t.tasktype task_type,
    t.description task_description,
    ord_comment.commenttext,  -- 2048 byte varchar2
    sim.msisdn target_msisdn, 
    o.reason reason_of_task,  -- 2048 byte varchar2
    DECODE(t.bussinesscategory,'0','Business Operation','1','Transaction and Action','2','Financial','3','Manual Task','4','Bulk','5'
,'Configuration','Others:'
    || t.bussinesscategory) businesscategory_of_task
FROM
    cpsmgt.cps_taskhis t --PARTITION ( SYS_P30212 ) t
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_operator op1 ON op1.operator_id = t.createid
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_operator op2 ON op2.operator_id = t.ownerid
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_role_operator ro1 ON op1.operator_id = ro1.operator_id
                                              AND op1.status <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN cpssys.cps_role_def rd1 ON rd1.role_id = ro1.role_id
                                         AND rd1.status = '30'
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_role_operator ro2 ON op2.operator_id = ro2.operator_id
                                              AND op2.status <> '06'
    LEFT JOIN cpssys.cps_role_def rd2 ON rd2.role_id = ro2.role_id
                                         AND rd2.status = '30'
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_order_comment ord_comment ON t.orderid = ord_comment.orderid
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_sim_device sim ON t.on_identity_id = sim.identity_id
    LEFT JOIN cpsmgt.cps_orderhis o ON t.orderid = o.orderid
WHERE
    t.createtime BETWEEN TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(20190404)
    || ' 00:00:00','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') AND TO_DATE(TO_CHAR(20190404)
    || ' 23:59:59','yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss')
    AND   t.procdefid IN (
        'IC_EditP2PMSISDNWorkflow',
        'IC_ResetCustomerPinWorkflow',
        'TC_TransactionConfirmWorkflow',
        'IC_ChangeCustomerProductWorkflow',
        'IC_EditG2PMSISDNWorkflow',
        'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityStatusWorkflow',
        'TC_CancelRemittanceWorkflow',
        'IC_ChangeCustomerMSISDNWorkflow',
        'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPINWorkflow',
        'IC_MigrateCustTrustL1Workflow',
        'IC_MigrateCustTrustL2Workflow',
        'IC_ChangeCustomerIdentityKYCWorkflow',
        'IC_UnblockPaymentTransactionWorkflow',
        'IC_ResetOrgOperatorPasswordWorkflow'
    )
    AND   rd1.name IN (
        'Complaints (Maker)',
        'MFS 1344 Help Line',
        'MFS 4444 Helpline',
        'Operator user(back end user) maker',
        'Complaints Checker',
        'Operator user(back end user) completer'
    )
    AND   rd2.name IN (
        'Complaints (Maker)',
        'MFS 1344 Help Line',
        'MFS 4444 Helpline',
        'Operator user(back end user) maker',
        'Complaints Checker',
        'Operator user(back end user) completer'
    );
```

Query Explain Plan (SQL Developer): (save the file as html and open in browser)

https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KBnhETTzgNLRUh7djyfCN-Wo5QxPZTfb

Important Notes : I am trying to insert the output to a temporary table. If instead i insert this data to a new table using create table as. The same query is working fine :-(

```
-- previous columns
   (
        SELECT 
            o.reason
        FROM
            cpsmgt.cps_orderhis o
        WHERE
            o.orderid = t.orderid
    ) reason_of_task,
-- rest of the query.
```

Comment: Can you show the definition of the index "cpsmgt.cps_orderhis.orderid"?

Comment: At first sight the indexes look good. Can you post the execution plan?

Comment: I am currently away from work due to weekend. Will surely do it first thing on Monday as I need to finish this work on Monday 

Comment: SQL Query Explain Plan also updated in Question : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1KBnhETTzgNLRUh7djyfCN-Wo5QxPZTfb

Comment: Index Definition : https://drive.google.com/open?id=1M-i2sf1Bw3WXAwUw9Of4doYuQ--0A2Qk55dNLSwTytg

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the following hint?

```
/*+ INDEX(o IDX_CPS_ORDERHIS_3) USE_NL(o t)*/
```

Maybe the OPTIMIZER does not choose the right index and choose USE_HASH for the execution plan.

Comment: Try to specify all indexes that you want to use and eliminate hash join by USE_NL.

Comment: How to do that  ?